# I am traveling to germany

Tags: usa, germany, children

I am 13. I have an arranged place to stay in germany for 1 year. I know german pretty well and intend to go to school there.I have US as well as German passports. What paperwork do I need to fill out?

Comment: You should check out what the requirements of the airline you’ll be flying with eg https://www.aa.com/i18n/travel-info/special-assistance/unaccompanied-minors.jsp

Comment: You shouldn't post too much personal information here, but: is that place with relatives of your family? Do they have children approximately your age? That would make things a lot more realistic.

Answer (score 3):

You write that you are 13 and that **you** have arranged a place. Under German law, your legal guardians have the right and duty to supervise your location in accordance with your age and maturity. They don't have to watch a 13-year-old every minute, but they do have to know and agree with your plan.

- As a German citizen, you need no visa. You do need a [written permission](https://www.bundespolizei.de/Web/DE/01Sicher-auf-Reisen/06Passrechtliche-Hinweise/02Reisen-mit-Kindern/reisen-mit-kindern_node.html) from your guardians stating your identity, their identity and contact information, a copy of their identity documents, your itinerary and destination, the identity of any adults you're traveling with.
- Usually, something like this is arranged with a student exchange program, but that is not strictly necessary. Your guardians could arrange for your stay with other responsible adults.
- The host family will need to register your residence with the municipal authorities.
- You will probably be *required* to go to school. That will follow when you register your residence.